# Convert index to datetime and get the time of Column 2 maximum

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe Looks like this:

```
0    203
1    250
2    318
3    786
4    321
5    135
```

I am trying to convert the index column to a datetime and Keep the second column.

```
pq = pq.index.to_datetime()
```

Output:

```
DatetimeIndex([          '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001',
               '1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002',
               ...]
```

This just creates a datetime dataframe from the index, doesn't it?

1) How do I 'replace' the index with a datetime while still keeping the rest of the dataframe?

2) What is the equivalent to pd.DataFrame.idxmax() for datetime?

Edit: My office's Pandas Version is 0.18.1

Edit2: A colleague helped me with this Problem;

```
date = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', end = '2017-12-31 23:45', freq = '15min')
pq.index = date
```

To get the time of column 2's Maximum:

```
pq.idxmax()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think need [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
pq.index = pd.to_datetime(pq.index)
print (pq)
                               col
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  203
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001  250
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000002  318
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000003  786
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000004  321
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000005  135
```

Also there is nice parameter `origin` for define start datetime (pandas 0.20.0+):

```
pq.index = pd.to_datetime(pq.index, origin=pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01'), unit='d')   
print (pq)
            col
2000-01-01  203
2000-01-02  250
2000-01-03  318
2000-01-04  786
2000-01-05  321
2000-01-06  135
```

For check max index is possible use [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
print (pq['col'].idxmax())
2000-01-04 00:00:00
```

EDIT:

For lower versions is possible use:

```
pq.index = pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(pq.index, unit='d')   
print (pq)
            col
2000-01-01  203
2000-01-02  250
2000-01-03  318
2000-01-04  786
2000-01-05  321
2000-01-06  135
```

Comment: `origin` is a nice touch

Comment: @piRSquared - I like it too :)

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. The first part works. But origin seems to not work on my machine. Output: TypeError: to_datetime() got an unexpected keyword argument 'origin'

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov - It seems your pandas version is below `0.20.0` - check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#to-datetime-has-gained-an-origin-parameter)

Comment: my office's Pandas Version is 0.18.1 , Is there a way to make it work in my case? It is not possible to update short term

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov - So it is reason, but what about `pq.index = pd.Timestamp('2000-01-01') + pd.to_timedelta(pq.index, unit='d')` ? Convert index to timedeltas and add datetime.

Comment: pd.to_timedelta(pq.index, unit 'd') results in a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ArturMüllerRomanov - Can you try copy it from edited answer? Sometimes code from comment replace `''` badly.

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately I am getting this: TypeError: astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'copy'

Comment: So, if use only `pq.index = pd.to_timedelta(pq.index, unit='d')` it working?

Comment: If use `pq.index = pd.TimedeltaIndex(pq.index, unit='d')` it working?

Comment: I solved the Problem with pd.date_range. It seems to work with pd 0.18 . Anyways, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the datetime as an index you can

```
pq.set_index(pd.to_datetime(pq.index), inplace=True, drop=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'set_index'. I am using Pandas 0.18.1, maybe that's why

Comment: Just check if the **pq** that you have defined in the start is a Series or a DataFrame.